# Interplay between axiomatic hyperbolic geometry and the hyperboloid model.

Tags: geometry, logic

If I can prove a statement about axiomatic hyperbolic geometry, in the language of the hyperboloid model, to be true, must it be true in the original axiomatic hyperbolic geometry?

I believe that the axioms for hyperbolic geometry are consistent (due to Beltrami). Does it follow that we can then engage in this interplay? This article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory#Using_the_compactness_and_completeness_theorems) seems to suggest that we can do so.

If possible, could you point me to some textbooks which deal with some of these questions (preferably with examples in a geometric setting)?

Thank you!

Comment: Nothing easy about this; I recommend the fourth edition of Greenberg along with Hartshorne. The unusual aspect is Hilbert's construction of the field of ends, by which the hyperbolic plane precedes the definition of the field of numbers indicated..... also page and article https://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/old-and-new-results-in-the-foundations-of-elementary-plane-euclidean-and-non-euclidean-geometries

Comment: The relevant question would be whether the axioms are complete, not whether they are consistent.

Comment: I suppose the answer is yes , but then What do you mean by “prove a statement about axiomatic hyperbolic geometry, in the language of the hyperboloid model“ ? Can you give some examples?  Also be aware we are talking philosophy here.